# Performance profiling asp.net, what is ProcessRequestNotificationHelper?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5, performance-testing

I'm performance profiling an asp.net web application, on a load of 20 users per second.  20 users are basically crippling the application and nothing it loading.

I'm using the RedGate performance profiler, and I'm not sure what to make of it.

12% of the time is spent in my code (which I can dig in to and improve)
but 88% of the time is spent in

System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(IntPtr rootedObjectsPointer, IntPtr nativeRequestContext, IntPtr moduleData, int flags)

..I've not a clue what this is (well, I'm fairly sure it's something to do with IIS7...), and tackling a site that's not able to cope with 20 users a second, at 88% of the time taken, this seems like a good place to start.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: This is time spent EXCLUSIVELY in ProcessRequeststNotificationHelper, not in anything it calls?

Comment: No - on analysing further, I think it might be one of the main entry points and so all of the other methods (which it has separated out...) may appear underneath it.  Still working through it

Comment: Just wondering if you ever figured this out.  I'm running into something similar.

Comment: This might help to investigate. http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Hosting/IPipelineRuntime.cs,6e1b32bebfaec851,references

Answer (score 2):

ProcessRequestNotificationHelper is simply the entry point for your profiling tool to capture data. Dynatrace, like RedGate, defines it as the entry point where their ASP.Net Sensor can begin tracing incoming requests in the ASP.Net pipeline.

https://community.dynatrace.com/community/display/DOCDT60/ASP.NET+Sensor