# .net System.Web.Hosting namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, memory-leaks

I have a problem with a method called `ProcessRequestNotificationHelper` that is supposed to be in the class `System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime`, but when I look [in the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting(v=vs.110).aspx#), I don't find the specified class.

Can you please explain me why?

this method is causing memory leak in one of my application (when profiled with dynatrace APM, is that related?)

Answer (score 1):

That's an [internal method](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Hosting/IPipelineRuntime.cs,6e1b32bebfaec851,references), so it isn't listed in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe SLaks here is correct in that since the PipelineRuntime class is internal, it doesn't appear in any documentation.

That said, it sounds like you're trying to do some performance profiling.  If you look at the following link, it's explained that Dynatrace just uses that as the entry point in your code. It's not that there's an issue in the ProcessRequestNotificationHelper method in particular as much as it's saying that there's an issue somewhere in your code:

[Performance profiling asp.net, what is ProcessRequestNotificationHelper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545025/performance-profiling-asp-net-what-is-processrequestnotificationhelper)

Comment: Yes, I earlyday saw that post, but could not access the community site of dynatrace since i don' have an account. But if it is an internal class, how the Dynatrace tool can access it?